# How do I turn off this annoying developers code completion?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The dev using the machine before me has set it up so when I create a new class file I get...

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="Chart.cs" company="ACompany">
//     Copyright (c) ACompany 2012. All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
// <author>Annoying Developer</author>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace ACompany.Core.POCO
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Add class description
    /// </summary>
    public class Chart
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the Chart class
        /// </summary>
        public Chart()
        {
            // TODO: Add default constructor logic
        }
    }
}
```

It's not the visual studio default, I want the default back how do I get it?

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Visual Studio template for a new class.

Here is [a link to the topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx) on MSDN.

[Customizing Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247119.aspx) is where you should start.